# Scraping Facebook users post by using Python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am new to Python and web scraping. I am working on scraping Facebook users post currently.

I found this example code of getting post of Facebook from https://gist.github.com/mylsb/10294040 (Library: Facebook SDK)
This code works well for getting data from the public page. However, when I try to get post from the user's profile (for example: https://www.facebook.com/bill.gate.7140497), I get the error message. How can I scape the user's post by using user Facebook ID?

Thank you!!!

```
import Facebook
import requests

def some_action(post):
    """ Here you might want to do something with each post. E.g. grab the
    post's message (post['message']) or the post's picture             (post['picture']).
    In this implementation we just print the post's created time.
    """
    print post['message']


access_token = ''
user = 'BillGates'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')

while True:
    try:
        # Perform some action on each post in the collection we receive from
        # Facebook.
        [some_action(post=post) for post in posts['data']]
        # Attempt to make a request to the next page of data, if it exists.
        posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['next']).json()
    except KeyError:
        # When there are no more pages (['paging']['next']), break from the
        # loop and end the script.
        break
```

Comment: I assume you read https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php ?

Comment: You can not access user posts unless the user logs in to your app and grants it permission.

Comment: Thank you guys!!!